# Escaping an Asterisks Using "CONTAINS" Function in SQLAnywhere

Tags: sql, escaping, contains, sqlanywhere

I'm attempting to write a query in SQL Anywhere that uses the CONTAINS function and searches for a literal asterisk.  I've used all the escape sequences I could find and none are working, the all return that an asterisk is prefix search only, so it appears to not be interpreting it literally.  I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionJournalDetail CONTAINS( TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_ReceiptAlias, '\*');

SELECT * FROM TransactionJournalDetail CONTAINS( TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_ReceiptAlias, '\\*');
```

-and-

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionJournalDetail CONTAINS( TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_ReceiptAlias, '\x2A');
```

-and-

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionJournalDetail CONTAINS( TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_ReceiptAlias, '[*]');
```

which I thought would work as according to the [documentation](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/817a3ded6ce21014bd99f3e554573180.html) I should be able to use the hex value, but it didn't work.  Any ideas on how to do this on SQL Anywhere would be great.

I know I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionJournalDetail WHERE TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_ReceiptAlias LIKE '%*%';
```

however I'd prefer to use the optimized CONTAINS.

Thank you!

Comment: No - sql anywhere is NOT based on sql server. Rather, MS originally licensed and used Sybase as the earliest version of sql server. That fact is irrelevant for current versions of either as MS developed their own code for later versions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, SMor, editing it now.